# Custom Print Layout in Powerpoint 2010

Tags: powerpoint

I'd like to print my slides in a 5 x 2 grid, meaning my slides will be printed in 5 rows and 2 columns (they're actually business cards).  PowerPoint 2010 only offers 4x2, 6x2 and 3x3 in the print menu.  Is there a way to achieve customs settings?

Answer (score 0):

Powerpoint doesn't offer custom settings like this, but there are other options.

One is to create your business card at the size you want it, group all the elements, then duplicate it 9 times and arrange the results in a 5x2 grid. That'll give you the best possible control over layout/positioning.

Another possible approach is to set the slide size up to your biz card size or something proportionally large.  Create the card design then save as PDF.  Finally print the PDF from Acrobat or Reader, where you can set up multiple "sheets" per page in custom layouts (ie your 5x2)